# Codeigniter get_where on active record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have trouble creating a query to get a specific data using codeigniter get_where function. I read and understand the manual and used it on my code but now when I was about to query from database like the code below it doesn't work.

Model:

```
public function load_parents () {
  $query = $this->db->get_where('checklist_items', array(('checklist_id' => $checklist_id) && ('parent_id' => $parent_id)));
  $result = $query->result_array ();
  return $result;
}
```

The Error:
**Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'**

I know the code is not right but is there another way to make it run?

Comment: missing `array` keyword `$checklist_id) && ('parent_id' => $parent_id)`

Comment: what do you mean by the keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
<?php 
public function load_parents () 
{
  $query = $this->db->get_where('checklist_items', array('checklist_id' => $checklist_id, 'parent_id' => $parent_id));
  $result = $query->result_array ();
  return $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('checklist_items', array('checklist_id' => $checklist_id, 'parent_id' => $parent_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
public function load_parents () {
 $query = $this->db->get_where('checklist_items', array('checklist_id' => $checklist_id , 'parent_id' => $parent_id));
$result = $query->result_array ();
return $result;
}
```

You can not use `&&` in array.

It will automatically consider `and`.

Another way is using where like

```
public function load_parents () {
 $query = $this->db
                   ->where('checklist_id' => $checklist_id)
                   ->where('parent_id' => $parent_id)
                   ->get('checklist_items');
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
}
```